# Copy data rows from excel files

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007, excel-2010

Hi, everyone!

I have a directory with files.
Every file has one worksheet.
I need to copy specified row (e.g. G:G) from every file to one master_file.xlsx (from where I start my macros).
One of problems is that rows are very big(about 2000 values), so my code throws warning for every iteation: large amount of information in clipboard.
Please help me with my attempts.
Great thanks!!!
My code is below:

Sub my_macros()

```vba
Dim sFileName, sNewFileName, myFile As String

sFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\master_file.xlsm"
If Dir(sFileName, 16) = "" Then MsgBox "Warning", vbCritical, "Error" Exit Sub
Cells.Select
Selection.ClearContents

For i = 1 To 5
    'MsgBox (i)
    sNewFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\file_" & i & ".xlsx"
    If Dir(sNewFileName, 16) = "" Then Exit For
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    'MsgBox (sNewFileName)
    Workbooks.Open sNewFileName
    Range("G:G").Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
    ThisWorkbook.Activate
    'Active
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns(2).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    'Workbooks(sNewFileName).Close SaveChanges:=False
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Switch to `ThisWorkbook` & insert *before* closing the newly opened workbook, then prior to `ActiveWorkbook.Close` simply swap out the large data in the clipboard with something smaller; `range("A1").copy`.